# Problema ao usar o PutExtra com um vetor

Tags: android, android-intent

Não consigo passar o vetor dentro do PutExtra. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Activity 1

```
 double[] valores = new double[vetorEdits.length];



            for (int i = 0; i < vetorEdits.length ; i++) {

                valores[i] = Double.parseDouble( vetorEdits[i].getText().toString());


            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(),Main5Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("valores", valores[vetorEdits.length]);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Activity 2

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

    double[] valores = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("valores", 0,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

O que você está a colocar nos extras é um double e não um array,

```
valores[vetorEdits.length]
```

é um double, aquele que está guardado no índice `vetorEdits.length`.

Julgo até que deva estar a dar erro n essa linha.

Deve usar assim:

```
intent.putExtra("valores", valores);
```

Para o recuperar deve utilizar

```
double[] valores = getIntent().getDoubleArrayExtra("valores");
```

Comment: Obrigado! No caso, como eu faço para usar um toast para imprimir os valores passados? Deu erro, da forma convencional. Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),valores,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: O que o Toast apresenta é uma String. Terá de "transformar" o array numa. Mas isso é outra pergunta. Entretanto veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) a forma de proceder quando uma resposta te foi útil.